# jump to last slide on load ngb-Carousel

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular 4 and ng-bootstrap carousel.
I would like to jump to last slide on load, tried using activeId but this doesnot helped

```
<ngb-carousel [activeId]="1">
```

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xWlKZjmX1aG5KmeSASqK?p=preview)

Comment: from https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1608, You need to:

    export the carousel component as a variable in a template, ex.: <ngb-carousel #myCarousel="ngbCarousel">
    give slides you want to select id, ex.: <ng-template ngbSlide id="mySecondSlide">
    select a desired slide by using the exported carousel instance and slide id, ex.: <button (click)="myCarousel.select('mySecondSlide')">Select second slide</button>

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. However i am unable to give an id to ngbSlide when it is generated using ngFor. Also i want to show last slide on page load with out any action. Can i get #myCarousel referance in ngOnInit ?http://plnkr.co/edit/xWlKZjmX1aG5KmeSASqK?p=preview

Comment: Use ViewChild to reference the carousel. see my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changes in your code

```
<!--check the template reference variable-->
<ngb-carousel #myCarousel="ngbCarousel" >
<!-- is "id={{i}} -->
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index" id="{{i}}">
    <h1>{{item}}</h1>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Your .ts must implements onInit and use ViewChild

```
import { Component, OnInit,  ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbCarousel,NgbCarouselConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-carousel-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/carousel-basic.html',
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]
})
export class NgbdCarouselBasic implements OnInit {
  //reference to "myCarousel"
  @ViewChild('myCarousel') myCarousel: NgbCarousel;
  private data = ["Slide 1","Slide 2","Slide 3"]
  //I prefered use private for all injected component
  constructor(private config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
    this.config.interval = 10000;
    this.config.wrap = false;
    this.config.keyboard = false;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myCarousel.activeId='2';  //<--use this, begans 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI you should put  this.myCarousel.activeId='2';  in the ngAfterViewInit hook not in ngOnInit

Comment: @Whisher, really you can do it in the ngOnInit (see http://plnkr.co/edit/nmrt5pyyAh2OZBME7c1w?p=preview) because "myCarrousel" is present at very early in the application

Comment: @eliseo I've got the carousel in a modal in the OnInit hook doesn't work

Comment: true. Only if the carrousel is present at firt of all (as the simple example I put) -sorry for confusion-. It definity correct make it in a ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: It is working for me only when I hover over the carousel !! why is that?

Comment: Really I don't know, look if there are errors in console and check that exist the "id"

Answer (score 1):

If anybody wondering why the `activeId` not works well for you,

then for the version:

```
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.4", // or above
```

You can make use of the `select()` method that `NgbCarousel` provides.

Suppose the id is `slideId-1` then do

```
 this.myCarousel.select('slideId-1');
```

In view file:

```
<!--check the template reference variable-->
<ngb-carousel #myCarousel="ngbCarousel" >
<!-- is "id={{i}} -->
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index" id="slideId-{{i}}">
    <h1>{{item}}</h1>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

in .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit,  ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbCarousel} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-carousel-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/carousel-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdCarouselBasic implements OnInit {
  //reference to "myCarousel"
  @ViewChild('myCarousel') myCarousel: NgbCarousel;
  items: object[];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMyItems(); // load items from an API
  }

  loadMyItems() {
    ...
    yourService.getItems().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.items = response.data;
        setTimeout(() => { this.scheduleCarousel.select('slideId-1') }); // if you are getting `.select() of undefined` error.
      }
    .....
  }
}
```

Here I provided an example of an API, you can follow the above answer if you have a static data.

Answer (score 0):

No need any change into your ts file. You need single quote here: 
 `<ngb-carousel [activeId]="'1'">`

And as the others mentioned, you need to the following in your template.
`<ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index" id="{{i}}">`